# Create histogram with column times another column

Tags: microsoft-excel

I am trying to create a histogram where one column has amount of days and another column has miles per day. I want to have a histogram where the x-axis is miles per day and the y-axis is days at that rate. For example:

<kbd>trip #</kbd><kbd>days</kbd> <kbd>mi/day</kbd>
<kbd>1</kbd>      <kbd>10</kbd>     <kbd>11</kbd>      
<kbd>2</kbd>      <kbd>1</kbd>       <kbd>23</kbd>      
<kbd>3</kbd>      <kbd>3</kbd>       <kbd>11</kbd>

would result in a frequency distribution of

<kbd>freq</kbd>  <kbd>bin (mi)</kbd>
<kbd>13</kbd>     <kbd>10-20</kbd>  
<kbd>1</kbd>       <kbd>20-30</kbd>

How do you export the first to the second in excel

Comment: The question seems confusing. The first part (creating a histogram) is easy with box charts. However the second part I'm not understanding how that enters into your question.

Comment: you got me, I was very confusing. I added the trip column. Basically, 3 trips, each varying in length of time and mileage. I want to know how many miles per day traveled

Comment: In that setting, a histogram wouldn't be the best format - I would recommend a scatter plot, which is also relatively trivial to do.

Comment: the range of values is 0-500 mi/day with 30,000 trips. That's why I wanted bins

Comment: Please try to explain everything in more detail... there are some people (like me) that may have forgotten or just don't know what are binomial distributions. With the data you provided here, there might be several ways to do what you want, ranging from COUNTIF to scatter plots, and so forth.